# Emphasising sentences

Tags: emphasis

It's pretty clear that using `do/did` we can emphasise a verb. Such as

```
I do recommend reading that book.
```

or

```
I did enjoy the movie.
```

But the question is, how to emphasise sentences like

```
I am keen to work with you.
```

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-to-add-emphasis-to-a-modal-verb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Words such as "very", "really", "quite" can be used to add emphasis to the word "keen" in the sentence, for example:

```
I am very keen to work with you.
```