# Can "be" be used with the modal verb "do"?

Tags: modal-verbs, emphasis, copular-verbs

These two sentences are both valid

> I write this sentence.
>
> I do write this sentence.

Are these both valid?

> I am writing this sentence.
>
> I do be writing this sentence.

Comment: The last is wrong.

Comment: [Robert Williams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Williams_(psychologist)) might say it do be... yo.

Comment: Do be a good fellow, won't you?

Comment: "I do be writing this sentence" sounds like pirate grammar. However, I searched the full text of Treasure Island and it doesn't seem to be used there.

Comment: @Robusto That is *imperative*. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Related: [How to add emphasis to a modal verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-to-add-emphasis-to-a-modal-verb).

Comment: "To be is to do" - Socrates
"To do is to be" - Sartre "Do
be do be do" - Sinatra

Answer (score 12):

The rule of [**Do-*Support***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66852/15299) applies to every main verb in English, except auxiliary verbs.

*Do*-Support is the process that provides the dummy auxiliary *do* to carry the tense and swap with the subject in *Yes/No*- and *Wh*-Questions

- ***Do*** you still love her?
- *What **do** you love about her?*

tag questions

- *You still love her, **don't** you?*

and negations

- *You **don't** love her any more.*

However, there are two important qualifications for this rule:

1. The verb *be* is **always** treated as an auxiliary verb, even if it's the only verb in its clause.  I.e, it can never invoke *Do*-Support. Which is the answer to the OP's question.
   Other isomorphs of *do* **can** occur with *be*, however:

   - *Do be a "Doo Bee", and don't be a "Dont Bee"*. - Emphatic *do*, active noun predicates.
   - *What I'm gonna do is be her bodyguard.* - Active *do*, active noun predicate.
2. The verb *have*, in its sense of "possess", may be treated

   - **either** as an auxiliary verb, i.e, commuting with the subject:  *Have you the time?*
     (marked as "British" in American English)
   - **or** as a main verb, i.e, allowing *Do*-Support:
     *Do you have the time?* (by far the more common choice in N. America)

Comment: Oh, by the way, _do_ is **not** a [modal verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html); it's just a dummy auxiliary verb, the same way _It_ in _It's easy to tell_ is a dummy pronoun; they're both put in as markers by the syntax and have no meaning.

Comment: +1 May I suggest, however, that you add your comment to the answer? It is germane to the issue at hand and not simply a comment on it.

Comment: Is it going to become invisible after a while or something? I do get tired of saying the same things over and over again; [the link](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) explains what the modals are, for anybody interested.

Comment: My point is that people don't always read comment chains. You are, of course, free to do as you like.

Comment: I think there's generally more interesting information in the comments than in the Official Answers; I've found no reason to distinguish between them. As to what people do or don't always read, that is completely not my responsibility so I don't worry about it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is the comment about emphatic *BE* meant to cover imperatives in general? *Don't be sad* doesn't seem to have an active predicate of any sort. I'm not sure it's emphatic either?

Comment: @Araucaria: No, "emphatic" does not cover "imperatives"; emphasizing is a very different thing from giving an order. As I said, _Do_-Support _do_, which is by far the most common -- and therefore is the first one to suspect and eliminate before considering other options -- is required for negatives. _Don't be sad_ is a negative. _Do be sad_ would be an emphatic.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, agreed. So doesn't this seem to undermine the assertion that BE doesn't take DO-support? (or rather is it an exception that might need to be added to the list?)

Comment: @Araucaria: Not at all. _Be_ is an auxiliary verb, and in _Don't be sad_ what is allowing the imperative in the first place is the active predicate adjective _be sad_. The _be_ is required for the predicate adjective, and if it weren't negative, that would be it -- no _Do_-Support: _Be sad._ But it **is** negative, and so _Do_-Support **is** required. But it's not "_be_ taking _Do_-Support", as you describe it. It's negation taking _Do_-Support and a predicate adjective taking _be_. Grammar is constructions, not a big bag of words.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, agreed, but as described *'he usually don't be sad'* might appear well formed, because you've described 'be sad' as an 'active' predicate. It's not clear why 'do' is not required for the negation of this predicate. In actual fact as we know we are stuck with 'He usual isn't sad' active reading or no.

Comment: @Araucaria: Other forms of _be_ invert and contract with negatives. But not the infinitive form _be_. It used to in older Englishes, but it doesn't now. And the infinitive form is required to make an imperative. So the fact that it's a predicate adjective requires some form of auxiliary _be_, the fact that it's an imperative determines that that form is the infinitive form _be_, the fact that infinitive _be_ can't alternate and contract requires a preceding _not_, and the fact that it's a negative without an alternating auxiliary requires _Do_-Support. Got all that?

Comment: @JohnLawler Right, so negative imperative constructions with BE invoke *Do*-support for the same reason that other constructions do. There is an auxiliary requirement in the construction which can't be met by another verb. However, this example is different from others because BE is still an auxiliary verb. It just can't perform the required function Is that right? (this is my last comment I promise!)

Comment: Just a few comments: 1) the correct context for do-support are negation, inversion (not just questions) and VP-ellipsis (not just tag-questions). 2) some speakers do allow do+be in irrealis context (e.g., “why don’t we be a low-tax country instead” - we should be vs. “why aren’t we a low tax country instead” - we in fact aren’t). 3) imperatives take do with be irrespective of emphasis (“don’t be an idiot” is far more common than “be not an idiot”). 4) the answer ignors dialects where do-support is more comprehensive, notably AAVE.

Comment: @RichardZ: Indeed. But on this question such details are extra trimmings. The people who submit questions here rarely expect (and almost never get) comprehensive answers. Plus, once we get down to details, it turns out that almost every person who answers questions here has their own set of terminology, rules, and phenomena to account for, so the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 6):

"I do be (something, something)....." is used regularly in everyday speech in South-East Ireland, where I grew up, but it is not regarded well, and a sign of being from a very specific type of rural, working class background.
Its used in this context as a continuous present:
"I do be always listening to that radio show on my way home from work"

Comment: Interesting!  It's also perfectly acceptable in AAVE, but as an emphatic.  "I don't think you be studying much based on your grades", "But I do be studying all the time!"

Answer (score 2):

What the second of the first pair is doing is adding emphasis. Because we normally use the auxiliary verb "*do*" in interrogative and negative sentences, not positive sentences.

> Question: **Do** you like apples?
>
> Positive sentence: You like apples.
>
> Negative sentence: You **don't** like apples.

However, "*do*" is used in a positive sentence to add emphasis.

Ex.

> [I **do** believe in fairies, I do! I DO!](http://staticyouth.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/i-do-believe-in-fairies-i-do-i-do/)

If my guess is right and you're trying to duplicate the act of emphasizing in the second pair, then it should be done this way:

First pair:

> I write this sentence.
>
> I **do** write this sentence.

Second pair:

> I am writing this sentence.
>
> I **am** writing this sentence.

As you can see, there is no need to add another auxiliary verb in the second pair because the word "*be*" or "*am*" is already one.

Answer (score 1):

*Do* is not usually used as a modal verb. Other answers have explained this and discussed the non-modal use of *do* with the verb *be*.

However, *do* is used as a modal verb to indicate continuous aspect, in some dialects English, as shown in [Do be doing be’s: habitual aspect in Irish English](https://www.google.com/amp/s/stancarey.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/do-be-doing-bes-habitual-aspect-in-irish-english/amp/).

Thus the strict answer to the question of whether the modal *do* can be used with the verb *be* is:

> Yes, **when** *do* is a modal verb it **can** be used with the verb *be*.

Answer (score -1):

All except the last are grammatical, but the second would be found only infrequently. In some regional dialects the construction illustrated by *I be writing this sentence* is also found.