# Ungrammatical: "Half the boys jumped, but only a quarter of the girls did."?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-ends, pro-verb-constructions

I'm writing a scientific paper and my coauthor claims that ending a sentence with "did" is ungrammatical. The sentence has the following form:

> Half the boys jumped, but only a quarter of the girls did.

Is he correct?

How can we describe the grammatical role that *did* is playing here, by standing in for the already-mentioned verb "jumped"? Is it a pro-verb (not to be confused with a proverb)? Where can I find rules for where pro-verbs can and cannot appear in sentences?

Comment: This is [Conjunction Reduction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299) with optional [_Do_-Support](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299). Yes, it is called a "pro-verb" (pronounced differently, of course), and _do_ is one of the most common pro-verbs. It is completely grammatical; your colleague is incorrect. Require them to cite a rule next time they try to correct your grammar.

Comment: It's a perfectly fine sentence.  Several ways one might reword it, but I doubt that any would be noticeably better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sentence is fine grammatically, and the pattern is very common in English in both informal and formal speech and writing.

*Did* is an auxiliary verb, but what is more interesting is what is NOT there: the verb *jump* is understood to be there grammatically, just like *you* is understood to be the subject in *Stop criticizing my grammar!*

This is an example of [verb phrase ellipsis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29).
From Wikipedia:

> Verb phrase ellipsis
>
> Verb phrase ellipsis (also VP-ellipsis or VPE) is a particularly frequent form of ellipsis in English. VP-ellipsis elides a non-finite VP. The ellipsis must be introduced by an auxiliary verb or by the particle to.
>
> *John can play the guitar; Mary can [play the guitar], too.* - VP-ellipsis
> *He has done it before, which means he will [do it] again.* - VP-ellipsis  
> An aspect of VP-ellipsis that is unlike gapping and stripping is that it can occur forwards or backwards. That is, the ellipsis can precede or follow its antecedent, e.g.
>
> *The man who wanted to [order the salmon] did order the salmon.* - VP-ellipsis
> *The man who wanted to order the salmon did [order the salmon].* - VP-ellipsis

Comment: The quote from the Wikipedia article is missing what looks like the all-important crossing out of what can be omitted. Your quote didn't make sense until I looked at the article. And just as I posted this you edited it. Ignore this, sorry.

Comment: Yes, I saw that at the same time you did [see it]. Thanks. :)