# "How do you call it" vs "How you call it" vs "How it's called", which way is correct?

Tags: grammar

I stumbled across the following in a conversation with a friend who is not a native English speaker. Considering the context, what is the correct way to phrase the  second sentence?

They said:

> I need to buy something. I am not sure how do you call it in English.

To me, this sounds incorrect but I am not sure why. I can think of a few different ways to rephrase it, but which one is actually grammatically correct?

> I am not sure how you call it in English.
>
> I am not sure what you call it in English.
>
> I am not sure how it is called in English.
>
> I am not sure what it is called in English.

Comment: If English is not your native language, then you may get better answers to questions like this at: ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would not use _how_ in most of these; _what it's called_ refers to the word, while ?_how it's called_ refers to method or means, and that's not the way English speakers refer to talking. As for the grammar, if a _Wh_-question is made into a subordinate clause (an "embedded question" clause), then [it doesn't invert the subject and auxiliary](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50012/15299) (and consequently doesn't need [_Do_-Support](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299)).

Answer (score 1):

> I  need    to  buy  something. I am not  sure  how  you  call  it  In English.

I think  the  sentence  is  wrong  since  the  subordinate  clause  is  in the  form  of  a  question.

The  correct  sentence  should  be:

> I am not  sure  how  you  call  it.

But  I  think  the  use  of how  is  wrong  in the  sentence.

We  use  how  to describe  a  process. If  we  want  to  know  about  a  thing  we  use  what.

For example:

How  do you  spell it in English ? what  do  you  call  it  in English?

I  think  the correct  sentences  are:

> I am not sure  what  you call  it  in  English.
>
> I  am not  sure  what  it  is  called  in English.

Here  are  two   links   which  show the  use  of whatand how.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what-do-you-call-it

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/how

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to ELU. The answer to your question is as simple as it is complicated.

There are many standard ways of saying things in one language of which there is no suitable word for word translation into English.  Romance languages are an example, such as French.

> What is your name?

The French do not say:-

> Quel est votre nom? (although a Frenchman would know what you are trying to say).

A Frenchman would say this:-

> Comment vous appelez-vous ?

And an Italian or a Spaniard would express the question is a similar fashion, as, in fact, would a Greek:  *Πως ονομάζεσθε* ("how are you called?")

So *how* can be ruled out straight away.  Both your other two might do, depending on the thing/idea/circumstance under discussion was.  So "I am not sure what it is called (or what you call it) in English are equally possible.  There is a third possibility:

I am not sure of the right word for it in English.

But that is no better than the other two.  Choice between these is a matter of personal choice.

Comment: @petitrien Oops, misled by the Latin ‘vestra’, left out the hyphen and never realised about the gap!  I’ll make the corrections.