# “Let Alone” in a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases, idioms

For the sake of grammar, is this phrasing correct:

> Python is something that not all adults know, let alone do the children.

or

> Python is something that not all adults know, let alone the children.

Can you indicate or provide the correct version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precise rules of the *let alone* construction are specified in great detail in
Fillmore, Kay, and O'Connor's classic 1988 article

> ["Regularity and idiomaticity in grammatical constructions: the case of ***let alone***"](https://user.phil-fak.uni-duesseldorf.de/%7Efilip/fillmore+88.pdf)
> *Language*, Vol. 64, No.3 (1988), pp 501-538

In particular, in this case, there should be no *do* in the *let alone* phrase. There is no fronting, negation, or inversion involved in this construction, and thus no need for [*Do*-Support](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299).

So the correct version is

- *Python is something that not all adults know, let alone the children.*

Comment: It might be worth it to point out that "let alone" is much more a spoken than written idiom. In writing, I would use "much less"....

Answer (score 1):

The usage is idiomatic rather than rigidly grammatical. *do* is not needed.

> Let alone = used to emphasize that something is more impossible than another thing:
>
> You couldn't trust her to look after your dog, let alone your child
>
> means “You would not trust her to look after your dog; it is even less likely that you would let her look after your child.”
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/let-alone)

Cambridge dictionary uses *impossible* but your example is better understood as *improbable*. “Few adults know Python; is is even less probable that children know it.” (This is the meaning of the sentence, regardless of any discussion of its truth)

Comment: Impossibility has degrees? Usage of this idiom is more general, for the informal negative expression of *a fortiori* reasoning.

Comment: Indeed, I agree, that is exactly my point. I feel that Cambridge dictionary has failed to distinguish between *impossible* (probability = 0) and *improbable* (probability small but not zero)

Comment: @BrianDonovan We often use “impossible” when we mean highly improbable or impractical, and in that sense it can have degrees. Or you could look at it as degrees of how *obviously* impossible something is.

Comment: @BrianDonovan To use impossible in your second sense - on occasion I would agree. To use in your first sense is loose and leaves the language with no word to describe that which cannot be, that which has zero possibility; we should not use it in that way.

Comment: @Anton Hyperbole is part of the language. Your chances of stopping it are *less than zero*. It is *beyond impossible*. ;-)