# Words like "do/does/did" to emphasize, but for "am/is/are"

Tags: verbs, emphasis, do-support

So X said to Y:

> I did tell you yesterday!

As far as I know, the word *did* there is to emphasize my point or tell him that I'm so sure I've told him the story yesterday. What I want to ask is, what's the word we may use to emphasize our point like that in a sentence with no verb? Like

> You ARE the one who breaks it!

For emphasis, I capitalized the *ARE*, but is there any word that functions like *did* does in the previous sentence?

Comment: In the first example, as you say, *did* is used for emphasis. Unemphasized one would say, simply, "I told you yesterday." (Note that early modern English, such as is found in Shakespeare or the King James bible, is replete with "He did [verb] ..." constructions which are used more for declamation than word emphasis.) When using a copula (verb of being, such as *is* or *are*), you have to rely on voice stress or italics to get the emphasis across.

Comment: Related: [Can “be” be used with the modal verb “do”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78549/can-be-be-used-with-the-modal-verb-do) and [How to add emphasis to a modal verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1659/how-to-add-emphasis-to-a-modal-verb).

Comment: Thank you very much for the editing, especially the tags (because actually I don't know which tag to be used) and for the links (because, I wanted to search it, but, just like the tags, I don't know what keyword I have to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Valery, verily I say unto you, you are **indeed** the messiah sent unto the world!
- Celery is **indeed** the food to eat to lose weight.
- I am **indeed** the one who killed her.
- You are **truly** a genius beyond normal proportions! Who would have thought of that?
- Veerasamy is **verily** a man of great faith.
- You are an **absolute** genius. How may I worship you?
- Laleetha and Gopisamee are **true** lovers of the divine kind.
- I have no **freakin** idea what you are talking about.

Verily is archaic use, and thus may be used in jest or sarcasm.

Comment: Naa, that's the word I'm searching for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you're trying to emphasize.

"Why do you break this?"
**You** are the one who breaks it!

"Why did you tell him I'm the one who breaks it?"
You **are** the one who breaks it!

"I'm the one who fixes it."
You are the one who **breaks** it!

Comment: So basically we can only morph the sentence , although the OP asked for an alternative word I was looking for a one word alternative. Anyway +1 for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

You can also say : you are **just** the one who breaks it!!